# How to Overlay Multiple images as per second on video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am overlaying images on video, I have go through many links but not get result what i am trying,

I am having multiple images name **frame0.jpg frame1.jpg frame2.jpg** and so on

So I try with this command

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", videoPath, "-i", dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
 + filePrefix + "1" + fileExtn ,"-filter_complex", "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]" ,
"-map", "[v]", "-map",  "0:a?", "-ac", "2", dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/out.mp4"};



ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171211_105946.3gp -i 
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame1.jpg -filter_complex 
[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v] -map [v] -map 0:a? -ac 2 
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/out.mp4
```

**ouput : Overlay a single image on video successfully**

I need to overlay the image per second on video and my images sequence is 
frame1.jpg, frame2.jpg and so on

**Trying Output** is each second new frame to be added on video.

Example :

second 1 : frame1.jpg

second 2 : frame2.jpg

second 3 : frame3.jpg

second 4 : frame4.jpg

```
Error Logs:
Metadata:
     major_brand     : 3gp4
     minor_version   : 0
     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
     creation_time   : 2017-12-11 05:29:46
     com.android.version: 6.0
     Duration: 00:00:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17382 kb/s
     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17378 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.01 fps, 30.01 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                                                               Metadata:
       rotate          : 90
       creation_time   : 2017-12-11 05:29:46
       handler_name    : VideoHandle
       Side data:
       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
 [mjpeg @ 0xf5b03800] bits 95 is invalid
 [mjpeg @ 0xf5b03800] bits 200 is invalid
 [mjpeg @ 0xf5b03800] Changing bps to 6
 [mjpeg @ 0xf5b03800] [IMGUTILS @ 0xff9086a0] Picture size 7168x52505 is invalid
 [image2 @ 0xf5b23600] decoding for stream 0 failed
 [image2 @ 0xf5b23600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
 /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame%d.jpg: could not find codec parameters
 Input #1, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame%d.jpg':
   Duration: 00:00:03.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
     Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
 [buffer @ 0xf5a7a000] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
 [buffer @ 0xf5a7a000] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
 [buffer @ 0xf5a7a000] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
 [buffer @ 0xf5a7a000] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
 [graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0xf5b17460] Error applying options to the filter.
 Error configuring complex filters.
                                                                                                           Invalid argument
12-12 12:21:09.298 22264-22264/com.package E/background: Finished command : ffmpeg
```

**This are files created**

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame1.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame2.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame3.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are named as a sequence, you can use

```
ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171211_105946.3gp -framerate 1 -i 
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/frame%d.jpg -filter_complex 
[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[i]fps=25[i];[m][i]overlay[v] -map [v] -map 0:a? -ac 2 
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/out.mp4
```

Comment: I try the code getting error edited question done

Comment: `Picture size 7168x52505 is invalid` --> if the images aren't corrupt, then these images are too big for ffmpeg. Resize them using some other app.

Comment: k, I will Resize the images and check the images